# Let $\phi\neq A\subset \mathbb{R}$ that is bounded from below. Show that there exists a decreasing sequence $(s_n)\subset A$ s.t. $\lim s_n = \inf A$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\phi\neq A\subset \mathbb{R}$ that is bounded from below. Show that there exists a decreasing sequence $(s_n)$ with $s_n \in A$ for all $n$ such that $\lim s_n = \inf A$.

My attempt:

Since $\phi \neq A$ is bounded below, then by the completeness axioms, $\inf A$ exists. Let $s=\inf A$.
By the definition of $\inf A$,

$s< s+\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

which means that we can find a sequence $s_n$ in $A$ such that

$s\leq s_n < s+\frac{1}{n}$. Hence $|s_n-s|<\frac{1}{n}\to 0$, so  $\lim s_n=s=\inf A$.

My issue is how to prove that $(s_n)$ is decreasing? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Edit:

consider $s_n=s+\frac{1}{2n}$. We have

$s+\frac{1}{2(n+1)}=s_{n+1}\leq s_n=s+\frac{1}{2n}$

which shows that $s_n$ is decreasing

Comment: Consider $s_n = s+\frac{1}{2n}$ and use squeeze theorem.

Comment: @ArunBharadwaj Thank you! I cannot see why do we have to use the squeeze theorem again. Would be enough to do as what I did in my post? (I edited it)

Comment: Oh yeah that works too. I was just saying squeeze theorem because $s \leq s_n \leq s+\frac{1}{n}$; and notice that $s_n$ is squeezed between the sequences $a_n = \{s\}$ and $b_n = \{s + \frac{1}{n}\}$. Now, $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} b_n = s$, so by squeeze theorem, you would also have $s_n \to s$. $s_n$ is decreasing by construction. So you are killing two birds with one stone. -- Just to reiterate though; what you edited also works.

Comment: @ArunBharadwaj Ok I see. Thank you so much, I appreciate your help.